# Rails doesn't work with restangular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I'm trying to get some data from JSON via Angular, but getting this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/movies.json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://blabla.herokuapp.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

But I have this config and there is right host:

```
var app = angular.module('Test', ['restangular'])
  .config(function (RestangularProvider) {

   RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("http://blabla.herokuapp.com");
   RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('.json');
   RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({xsrfCookieName:'csrftoken', xsrfHeaderName:'X-CSRFToken'});
});
```

On the local machine this works fine(if I replace setBaseUrl of course)

Comment: Did you try abandoning `RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("http://blabla.herokuapp.com");` line altogether? If you serve your Angular app with the same Rails app that provides JSON, you most certainly don't need it. Serving using relative URLs will prevent you from getting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" errors.

Comment: Yes, I tried. Same result - `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/movies.json`. Maybe heroku doesn't support api requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in assets(js files). 
Need to do `rake assets:precompile` before deploy on heroku or include rake/assets/* in `gitignore`.